# How to ignore foreign key constraint to delete in hibernate/jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, heroku-postgres

[image]

I tried this

```
userRepository.delete(existingUser);
```

but got this error. How do I ignore foreign key constraint in hibernate

Comment: There's nothing to ignore. The error is telling you that you cannot delete the element because some other row in a table is referring to it. You first need to delete the association.

Comment: So how do I delete the association

Comment: The error is telling you that there is a row in `cast_call_applicants` referencing the row in `user_table` that you are trying to delete.

You need to make sure that the row in `cast_call_applicants` is updated before deleting the user.

How this is done, it depends on the mapping you are using. Hard to say without the entities. You should check the Hibernate ORM docs for examples: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many